# vagrant synced folder is git repository but need to separate into separate repositories

Tags: git, github, vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm struggling with an issue with my Vagrant virtual machine. I have several projects that I need to work on in that machine. When I first set it up I cloned a git repo that I was working on. Now all of my subsequent projects that need to live in the VM are part of that original git repo. The repo includes the vagrant folder with the Vagrantfile that is synced to my host. Everything I do in the synced folder is part of that git repo, even though they should be separate projects.

Option A:
Change the synced folder by going up a level so I can add some new folders and create a new git repo for my other project(s)

Option B:
Change the Git repo to go down a level so my current projects can be split apart to more efficiently contain the projects that already exist in subdirectories.

Currently the dir structure looks like this
Vagrant (Git repo, synced folder)
--Vagrantfile 
--several subdirectories containing separate projects.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Github repository and then deleted the git files within the local repository.
I created new Github repositories for each project.
Then I went down a directory and did git init new repositories for each of the separate projects.
    git init
Then I did 
    git add
    git commit
    git push origin master
This updated my Github.
Now I have no history or log entries but I can work withing this Vagrant box on independent processes so I can move forward.